# Can Selenium WebDriver open a link in a new tab from the current window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to automate the task that when a link from the existing browser session is clicked, the link should open a new tab within the existing browser session. 
I was able to get the new session opened as a new window but not as a tab.
Does Selenium 2.0 support the above task. If so could someone please post some generic code/logic on how this can be implemented.
I am stuck at this point as the product I am working on will open the new link only in a tab  when testing manually which needs to be automated. Thanks

Comment: css 3 has the ability to instruct a new window to be opened as a tab. `{ target-new: tab}` Selenium should treat it as if it is a window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032230/selenium-2-open-link-in-new-tab-and-close-tabs

Comment: http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/How-to-open-a-link-in-new-tab-td17997.html

Comment: How can I save the window handles so that the initial tabs can be revisited