# How to transfer control to new tab in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to transfer control from old tab to new tab using WebDriver? 
Suppose I open a link in new tab and then I want to perform some actions in that newly open tab. How can I do this?

When I open a link in new tab, the control still exist in old tab. Please provide a solution.

For example: I opened the link "Create a account" in gmail to new tab and then I try to fill text fields available in form, but when I run the program, it always say that elements not found

Thanks.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Java, python, C# or what?

Comment: You need to handle the windows/tabs by using getWindowHandle() and getWindowHandles() methods of WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")),Keys.NUMPAD2).build().perform();
```

will pass the control to new tab (this script assumes new tab is second tab).

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

This will close the new tab.

```
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")),Keys.NUMPAD1).build().perform();
```

Will switch back to original tab.

Related questions
[Selenium 2: Open link in new tab and close tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032230/selenium-2-open-link-in-new-tab-and-close-tabs)
[switch tabs using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Hi,
this is my code:

public void test() throws Exception
 {
  WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http:/www.gmail.com");
  WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create an account"));
  Actions oAction= new Actions(driver);
  oAction.moveToElement(element);
  
  oAction.contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("gaurav");
  driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).sendKeys("saini");
 }

I opened 'Create a account' in new tab and want to fill form

Comment: But control is still in previous tab, it always says element not found, please help for this how to get over from this.

Answer (score 0):

```
//declare selectLinkOpeninNewTab above the main method 
static String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN);

// to open your seession in new tab
driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// to perform actions
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.NUMPAD2);   

// for example thease are your actions
driver.findElement(By.id("")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("")).clicl();

// to close new tab and back to current tab
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"w");
```