# How to Open link in new tab and close tab in selenium 3?

Tags: java, selenium, tabs

Before tagging this as duplicate. Please read the Question. i have seen many answers for this kind of question. But none of them really worked. The closest that worked is this code below by twobytehero..

[Selenium 2: Open link in new tab and close tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032230/selenium-2-open-link-in-new-tab-and-close-tabs)

But its opening a window instead of a tab and i am not able to control the delay. I am using selenium 3. Using Selenium WebDriver with JAVA , I am trying to automate a functionality where I have to open a new tab do some operations there and come back to previous tab (Parent). Whats the best possible way to do it with firefox ??

Comment: clicking on a link should open a new tab with that url and i need to do certain operation and return back to parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use approximately the same approach.
For opening new tab use shortcut:

> Ctrl + T

For navigating to previous tab:

> Ctrl + Shift + Tab

For closing current tab:

> Ctrl + W

Code snipped for opening new tab can look like following:

```
public static void openNewTab() {
    String openNewTabCombination = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t");
    driver.get().findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(openNewTabCombination);
}
```

Also for moving to another tab with `RemoteWebDriver` you can use:

```
public static void moveToAnotherTab(RemoteWebDriver driver) {
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is  while clicking on                                                          WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='confirmButtons'/a[1]"));                         
elem.click();                                                                                                  it should open that link in a new  tab. can you please tell how to achieve that?

Comment: @LijoPhilip Have you tried following - click by right mouse button and select open in the tab?

Comment: Nope. How to do it? Can You help?